# How to change carrier name on Xcode 9 iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, carrier

Hello is it possible to change carrier name on Xcode 9.3?
This is line doesn't have springboard.strings and all answers just from 2010-2016 years..but anyway maybe somebody found solution? Thanks.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/French.lproj/SpringBoard.strings

[image]

UPDATE: I found awesome solution - https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic
[image]